# SharePoint get "Modified By" field from Library using REST API

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-library

I want to retrieve the OOTB Modified By value using REST API. 
I tried the below options in my REST Query:

```
Editor/Title&$expand=Modified By
Editor/Title&$expand=Editor
```

I am getting the error : **The expression "Modified By" is not valid.**

Please suggest how to achieve this?

To check the "Modified By" field name , I have queried all fields using below request:

```
https://servername/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyLibrary')/Fields?$select=Title,InternalName
```

Here's the response for "Modified By":

```
<d:InternalName>Editor</d:InternalName><d:Title>Modified By</d:Title>
```

Please help me here!

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, do you want to get the value of modified by field for the item?

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `expand` with the this `Editor` field.

In the `$expand`, you should specify the person field you want to expand.

`$select=Editor/Title&$expand=Editor`

Try below query:

```
https://servername/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyLibrary')/fields?$select=Title,InternalName,Editor/Title&$expand=Editor
```

Comment: I tried the below query: `https://servername/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Pages')/items?$Select=Created,ID,Title,Modified,Status,CurrentAuthor/Title&$expand=CurrentAuthor,Editor/Title&$expand=Editor` I have two people columns - one is CurrentAuthor and other is Editor(ModifiedBy). This query works for CurrentAuthor but does not work for Editor. It throws error **"The query to field 'Editor' is not valid. The $select query string must specify the target fields and the $expand query string must contains Editor."**

Comment: You cant use multiple `$expand`. The query should be as below:

`https://servername/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Pages')/items?‌​$Select=Created,ID,T‌​itle,Modified,Editor/Title,Status‌​,CurrentAuthor/Title‌​&$expand=CurrentAuth‌​or,Editor`

Answer (score 7):

You can use below syntax

```
$select=Editor/Title&$expand=Editor/Id
```

You query will turn into

```
https://servername/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyLibrary')/Items?$select=Title,InternalName,Editor/Title&$expand=Editor/Id
```

Comment: Thank You for the response, now am getting this error **"The query to field 'Editor' is not valid. The $select query string must specify the target fields and the $expand query string must contains Editor."**

Comment: The end point for getbytitle("mylibrary")/Fields don`t provide ModifiedBy information.

Comment: Is this not achievable? To fetch OOTB ModifiedBy field using REST API? Please guide me if I am missing something here. ThanQ!

Comment: Are you looking for field modified by or item modified by column? In the question you are referring "<d:InternalName>Editor</d:InternalName><d:Title>Modified By</d:Title>" is a peroperty of a list item not a field property. Check this query for field property siteurl/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('listtitle')/Fields?$filter=InternalName eq 'Title'